# Creating charts in java or javascript without images

Tags: javascript, java, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

One of the project requirements for my new java web project is to have dynamic charts that will load really fast.

While in discussion , it was asked if we could implement charts without using images ie without loading jpg, png files etc. Also files like pdf cannot be used.

Basically my question is

1. Can charts be implemented in jsp/javascript without using images,pdf etc ?
   ie even api's used should not provide end result as image,or pdf etc.
2. I did not say no right away , as I have implemented charts in console applications in C on screen.  Can we do something like that on a webpage ? ie show a graph by drawing on screen dots,lines,circles etc.But it should be possible inside a div ?

**PS : Comments and answer from  Lucien Stals helped to understand that the technology i was looking for was svg.**

I am looking for some nudging in the right direction from some of the experienced java , javascript programmers in SO.

Comment: Yes these possibilities do exist. I still consider the question off topic and have a hard time believing that google searches such as "render chart javascript" didn't return anything.

Comment: @reto I did search the topic in google.  I did find javascript api's. But again my doubt in that was if they used images in the end result. ie they created an image from my data and put it in the page.  I cannot use images (nor can the apis i use) . Thinking more in terms like drawing vector images on screen.

Comment: Could you draw DIVs and size and color them with CSS? Or if you want vector images, then what about a library like http://raphaeljs.com/ ? But I can;t get my head around what you mean by "no images". Isn't a vector graphic still an image?

Comment: @LucienStals Could you draw DIVs and size and color them with CSS ? maybe. I am looking for solutions like that . I may be technically wrong when i said vector images. what i meant was like drawing a circle on screen in old c console programs and coloring , drawing lines inside it. . Can some thing like that be done on a div on  a webpage.

Comment: A simple bar chart would be easy enough with DIVs and css. Anything more complicated and I think you are talking SVG, which could be drawn using raphael, or maybe http://d3js.org/ . Also look at the HTML5 canvas element.

Comment: @LucienStals Thanks . your last comment really helped me. I think svg could be the way to go for me and thanks for the raphaeljs and d3js links. Could you please create an answer with the contents of your last comment ? so that i can mark the question as answered.

Comment: No worries @Raj . Answer posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bar chart would be easy enough to create with DIVs and CSS.
Anything more complicated and I think you are talking SVG, which could be drawn using http://raphaeljs.com/, or maybe http://d3js.org/ . 
Also look at the HTML5 canvas element.

Answer (score 4):

Many JavaScript chart libraries exist that render in HTML5 on your page. You can probably find one that meets other requirements or wishes of your team, since each have feature areas in which they excel. http://www.zingchart.com has also been adding many ways to include them in your charts if you decide to go with something other than vanilla JavaScript (jQuery, Angular, etc). Full disclosure: I'm on the ZingChart team. I can help you weigh the pro's and con's if you find a few that catch your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [Google Chart Framework.](https://developers.google.com/chart/) I did use it in past for my project and it is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can check highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/ . This can be integrated easily with your javascript .

Answer (score 0):

Most of this js chart plugins expects data in array or json format and can dynamically render the charts.Easy to integrate in the web pages

jgccharts.js  [Jquery charts](http://durgaprasadtechie.blogspot.in/2011/07/jquery-charts.html)

[jquery charts plugin](http://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/)